# IntellijIDEA does not recognize play framework JPA Helper

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Intellij Idea does not recognize Play Framework dependencies, so my project works properly.
I had been installed **Play 2.0 support** plugin for my intellij idea 13.
I cant gave any auto complete for JPA helper class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Play's JPA functionality is not present by default. Add `javaJpa` to your dependencies in your `build.sbt`. Refresh your IDEA project or restart IDEA to get it to pick it up.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   // Other dependencies
   javaJpa,
   // Other dependencies
)
```

Comment: For anyone arriving here via Google: This was actually a magic fix which resolved the problem described, but with the latest IntelliJ (14.1) and Play (2.3).